# Thread-safe lazy initialization

Tags: java, thread-safety, lazy-initialization

I've read about thread-safe lazy initialization and I look at the implementation of the hashCode method in the String class. Apparently this method is thread-safe, I made my own version of it for another class (immutable).

```
private int hashcode;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hashcode;
    if (h == 0 && array.length > 0) {
        hashcode = (h = Arrays.hashCode(array));
    }
    return h;
}
```

My question is : Is it really thread-safe ? I don't understand why.
I do not see what prevents a thread to enter the method while another is still inside, but maybe it got it wrong.

Comment: Thread-safety isn't equivalent to mutual exclusion. It doesn't mean that only one thread can execute the method at a time. It means that, whatever the number of threads calling the method, in whatever order, concurrently or not, they will all get the correct result, and leave the object in a correct state. The thread-safety of that method mainly depends on the immutability of the array.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I understand now, the worse that can happen is the hashcode is calculated several times. But that is not dangerous because since the object is immutable, the hashcode will always be the same.

Comment: That's not actually the worse. The worse would be that Arrays.hashCode() returns 0, which would cause the hashCode() to be recomputed *every time*. This problem has been used as a way to create clever DDOS attacks by submitting long strings that were known to have a 0 hashCode.

Comment: Should I add a condition to prevent this ?

Comment: You can't prevent it with the code you have. It might not be a real problem, only a very rare, minor missed performance optimization. If you absolutely want to prevent it, you'll have to store the fact that the hashCode hasn't been computed yet, somehow (using a null Integer rather than an int set to 0, for example).

Comment: What about a boolean ? It seems more appropriate.

Comment: A boolean doesn't allow to set the hashCode atomically without some kind of synchronization: a thread would toggle the boolean and set the hashCode, and another thread could see the toggled boolean, but not the correct hashCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JB Nizet pointed out, the main problem is that you could have a non-empty array whose hash happens to be `0`.  You need to be able to distinguish "Hash is really 0" from "Hash is unknown".  You could use a nullable `Integer` for this:

```
private final AtomicReference<Integer> hashcode = new AtomicReference<>();

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    Integer h = hashcode.get();
    if (h != null) return h;
    int computedHash = Arrays.hashCode(array);
    hashcode.compareAndSet(null, computedHash);
    return computedHash;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you are seeing is just possibly inefficient. What could happen is that multiple threads enter the `hashCode()` function at the same time and they both compute the hash code instead of just one of them computing the hash code and the others waiting for the result.

Because `String` is immutable, this is not a problem. If the object was mutable, it would need synchronization in its `hashCode()` function (because the object's state could be changed whilst inside of `hashCode()`.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that my object is immutable